# Find the line equation $ax + by+ c =0$ from point and angle.

Tags: geometry

Given a point $P$ and an angle $\alpha$ (see image) how does one find the corresponding line equation on the form $ax + by + c = 0$?

[An image of a point $P$ and an angle $\alpha$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhUBC.png)

Comment: Do you mean $ax+b\color{red}{y}+c=0$?  It would help to know what your thoughts are.

Comment: Yes, I will edit it, thank you

Comment: Slope $m=\tan \alpha$, then by point-slope form $$y-y_P=m(x-x_P)$$

Comment: Notice that $\tan(\alpha) = -1/2$ and the line passes through the point $(0,4)$.

Comment: From the image, though, it appears you have no use for $\alpha$.

Comment: I'm looking for general solution for all possible values of $\alpha$, so the image is just an example. Hence also for $\alpha = \pi / 2$, there the slope m is infinite. Which is why I have not been able to solve it and also why the solution from Ng Chung Tak does not work

Comment: @sky_e in such case, the line equation is given by $x = c$, where $c$ is the abscissa of the points where the line passes through.

Comment: Yes, but I'm looking for a procedure which will work in all cases, hence so it can implemented in code without if statements. The problem seems simple enough for one to exists. I have just not been able to come up with one. Hence my post :)

Comment: Compute the normal form $x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta=d$ where of course the direction of the normal is given by angle $\theta=\alpha\pm\frac\pi2$ (choose a sign to fix the orientation) and $d$ you can calculate from the point $P$ and angle $\theta$.

Comment: @user10354138 Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\newcommand{\bv} {{\mathbf v}}
\newcommand{\bu} {{\mathbf u}}
$$
If the line direction is $\alpha$, then a vector pointing along the line is $\pmatrix{\cos \alpha \\ \sin \alpha}$. Rotating counterclockwise by 90 degrees, we get that the vector $\bv = \pmatrix{-\sin \alpha \\ \cos \alpha}$ is perpendicular to the line. That means that if $\bu$ is any vector pointing along the line, we know that $\bv \cdot \bu = 0$. Hold that thought.

Now we have a point $(x_1, y_1)$ on the line, and if $(x,y)$ is an arbitrary point on the line, then $\bu = \pmatrix{x-x_1 \\ y - y_1}$ is a vector pointing along the line, so $\bv \cdot \bu = 0$. Writing that out, we get
\begin{align}
0 
&= \bv \cdot \bu \\
&= \pmatrix{-\sin \alpha \\ \cos \alpha} \cdot \pmatrix{x-x_1 \\ y - y_1} \\
&= -\sin (\alpha) (x-x_1)+ \cos (\alpha) (y - y_1) \\
\end{align}
Separating out the coefficients of $x$ and $y$, we get
$$
-\sin(\alpha) x + \cos(\alpha) y + (\sin(\alpha)x_1 - \cos(\alpha)y_1) = 0
$$
which has the required form.

Notice that my form for $c$ is simpler than yours --- that's because you have both $x_1y_1$ and $-x_1 y_1$ in yours.

Comment: Thank you! That solution is more elegant than mine!

Comment: It also works in higher dimensions, except that "rotate 90 degrees" isn't uniquely defined. In $n$ dimensions, you have to start with $n-1$ vectors lying IN the plane and compute their generalized cross product to get an $n$th vector perpendicular to the plane; everything else remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

I did manage to solve it myself. Here is my solution:

Finding a line on the form $ax+by+c=0$ from a point and an angle:

Let $P_1:(x_1,y_1)$ be an arbitrary point and $\alpha$ be an arbitrary angle which together define a line in the plane. Then a new point $P_2$ on the line can be constructed by taking a unit step along the direction given by $\alpha$ hence $P_2:(x_1+cos(\alpha),y_1+sin(\alpha))$.

Then from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422602/convert-two-points-to-line-eq-ax-by-c-0/422608#422608) we know a point $P:(x,y)$ lies on the line connecting $P_1$ and $P_2$ if and only if the area of the parallellogram with sides $P_1P_2$ and $P_1P$ is zero. This can be expressed using the determinant as
$$
\begin{align}
\begin{vmatrix}
(x_1+cos(\alpha))-x_1 & x-x_1 \\
(y_1+sin(\alpha))-y_1 & y-y_1
\end{vmatrix} = 0 \\ \Longleftrightarrow 
(y_1-(y_1+sin(\alpha)))x+((x_1+cos(\alpha))-x_1)y+x_1(y_1+sin(\alpha))-(x_1+cos(\alpha))y_1=0 \\ \implies 
-sin(\alpha)x+cos(\alpha)y+x_1(y_1+sin(\alpha))-y_1(x_1+cos(\alpha))=0
\end{align}
$$
Hence (up to scale) $a =-sin(\alpha)$, $b=cos(\alpha)$ and $c=x_1(y_1+sin(\alpha))-y_1(x_1+cos(\alpha))$.

Answer (score 0):

Use trig.

If we imagine a bug traveling along the line for $1$ unit.  The number of units in the $x$ direction will be $\cos \alpha$ units, and the number of units in the $y$ direction will be $\sin \alpha$ units.

For any given point $(x,y)$ then change in vertical direction, ($y-y_0$) will be in proportion to the change in horizontal direction, $(x-x_0)$ as $\sin \alpha$ will be to $\cos \alpha$.

That is $(y-y_0):: (x-x_0) \sim \sin \alpha :: \cos \alpha$ so

$\cos\alpha(y-y_0) = \sin \alpha (x-x_0)$.

You might note that using the old idea of "slope/point" formula where $y = mx + b$ or $y-y_0 = m(x-x_0)$ or $\frac {y-y_0}{x-x_0} = m$.  This is  quite simply, $m = \frac {\sin \alpha}{\cos \alpha}=\tan \alpha$.

As you point out in a comment, the fails if the line is vertical and the slope $m$ is infinite and $\alpha = \frac {\pi}2$ and $\tan \alpha = \infty$.

But our old slope/point formula failed in those cases anyway.

..... cut the below ......

Using trig we get $\cos \frac \pi 2(y - y_0) = \sin\frac \pi 2(x-x_0)$

$0 = x-x_0$ and $x = x_0$ is the formula.

SO the slope of the line is $\frac {\sin \alpha}{\cos \alpha} = \tan \alpha$.

And that's it. Once we have the slope and a point we are done.

If the point is $x_0, y_0$ then we have the equation is $(y-y_0) = m (x-x_0) = \tan \alpha (x-x_0)$.

That's all.

Comment: This will not work in general e.g. if $\alpha = \pi / 2$.

Comment: True... but if $\alpha = \frac \pi 2$ is as exception.  If $\alpha =\frac \pi 2$ then the equation is just $x= x_0$..... Actually, you make a good point. We learn the $y= mx +b$ formula and skirt over the case of vertical lines when $m$ is infinite.  In this case $\sin \alpha(y-y_0) = \cos \alpha (x - x_0)$ will handle that just fine.